# How can i copy a folder from inside my running application jar file to some other directory in the operating system

Tags: java, jar, resources, copy, directory

I have looked at other questions on SO but most of the solutions dont work and the ones that work are too lengthy and difficult to understand.What i want to accomplish is that i have a project folder named "TEST" in there i have project subfolders namely "bin","src" and some other files.Inside "src" folder i have my package folder "pack" in which i have my classes and resources that i use in my program i also have a folder in this directory named "MARS".Now i must somehow copy the "MARS" folder mentioned above to some directory in the operating system , which i am doing as follows :

```
    String path = TESTER.class.getResource("").getPath() ;
           path = path.replace("%20", " ");
           path = path.replace("bin","src") ;
           path = path + "MARS" ;

           File srcDir = new File(path);
           File destDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+ "\\MARS");
           FileUtils.copyDirectory(srcDir, destDir);
```

This works like a charm when i am working with the project in eclipse, but when i package the application in a runnable jar file it doesn't work.I need the similar function to be performed when the MARS folder is packed inside my application jar file. I don't know any advance concepts of java as i am a 3rd semester student in a university, so i am expecting a solution with some explanation.I know this is a duplicate question but i really didn't find any of the solutions in other questions easy to understand and i don't want to copy and paste code someone else has written without understanding each and every thing in it.

Comment: Have you tried an absolute path? ( getResource("/src/MARS/..." ) - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)

Comment: Tried that without any luck ):